# How can I print variable in twig

Tags: php, twig, slim

**How can I Use {{dump(variable_name)}}
Here if result is a variable**

```
<pre>
    {{dump(result)}}
</pre>
```

Answer (score 1):

php
`->get('field_example')` and `->field_example`

are the same and so is TWIG

`.get('field_example')` and `.field_example`

both get the field object (field item list) from which you can get the field value(s).

`{{ content.field_example }}`

hope answer the questions

Comment: can you pls answer it like my example

Comment: if my variable is result then how should i write the code in twig file

Comment: The dump function is not available by default. You must add the \Twig\Extension\DebugExtension extension explicitly when creating your Twig environment:

$twig = new \Twig\Environment($loader, [
    'debug' => true,
    // ...
]);
$twig->addExtension(new \Twig\Extension\DebugExtension());
Even when enabled, the dump function won’t display anything if the debug option on the environment is not enabled (to avoid leaking debug information on a production server). after that 
<pre>
    {{ dump(result) }}
</pre>

Comment: can you pls write code for the same in my given container

Comment: $container['view'] = function ($container) {
    $view = new Twig('../Resources/Views/Users', [
        'cache' => false
    ]);

// Instantiate and add Slim specific extension
    $router = $container->get('router');
    $uri = Uri::createFromEnvironment(new Environment($_SERVER));
    $view->addExtension(new TwigExtension($router, $uri));

    return $view;
};                                                                                                                                                                                                                          In this